# fetch multiple api requests, parse once, in Google Apps script, doe

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble with the fetchAll method for UrlFetchApp.

I'm currently running multiple functions to gather api data from a handful of links with slight variations in api actions.  All functions are returning and parsing data under consistent JSON fields.  I want to have one function to retrieve the api data at once, parse once, and output once.  I thought fetchAll would be the better method of doing this.  The output will be to a spreadsheet.

Below is a variation of the script simplified for privacy.  I keep getting "Cannot find method fetchAll(object,object)" error at line 14.  I have tried fetching the urls with UrlFetchApp.fetchAll[eth,btc] and this gets me past the error but then "Cannot call method 'getContentText' of undefined".

Can't seem to figure out the correct way to do this from the [Google Apps documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)).  No help from google discussion group so far.

Do I need to incorporate the parse as an object within the fetchAll method?

```
function dailyhx() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DailyHx');  
  var eth = {
    'url' : 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=ETH&tsym=USD&limit=10',
    'method' : 'get',
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
  };
  var btc = {
    'url' : "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=10",
    'method' : 'get',
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
  };
  var mph = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(eth, btc)
  var j1 = JSON.parse(mph.getContentText());
  Loager.log(j1)
}
```

Comment: What is doe? Oddly curious

Comment: Doe=though.  As in, "I want the script to work, but it won't, doe."

Comment: Thought so didn't want to assume that doe.

Comment: Isn't it spelled, "doh"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()` function only expects one parameter which must be an array.

So replace this:

```
var mph = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(eth, btc);
```

with this:

```
var requests = [eth, btc];
var mph = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
```